# How I can collect similar xml tag to groups with Xml.Linq in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have a xml file with this style

```
<all_elements>
    <elements>
            <element attribute="7" />
            <element attribute="1" />
            <element attribute="6" />
    </elements>
    <elements>
            <element attribute="2" />
            <element attribute="8" />
    </elements>
    .
    .
    .
</all_elements>
```

I want calculate average of each **elements** seprate with c# Xml.Linq, for exapmle:

```
average1= 4.66
average2= 5.00
```

I know that I must use XElement or XDocument type and use Query on XML and I can calculate sum & average of all element without consider top-level tag (**elements**), But I don't know how to calculate average of each **elements**...

How I can do this with with c# Xml.Linq? any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a nested query:

```
root.Elements("elements").Select(
    e => e.Elements("element").Average(f => (int)f.Attribute("attribute"))
)
```